# How to use python output as input for next step in argo workflow?

Tags: python, argo

Based on the last line of the output of a python script (I cannot adapt the output-format) I want to trigger multiple new steps in argo-wf. How can I ignore all output lines except the last one in below example? I cannot adapt thy python-code so I guess I have to include an additional step to exclude all lines except last one.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-param-result-
spec:
  entrypoint: loop-param-result-example
  templates:
  - name: loop-param-result-example
    steps:
    - - name: generate
        template: gen-number-list
    - - name: sleep
        template: sleep-n-sec
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: seconds
            value: "{{item}}"
        withParam: "{{steps.generate.outputs.result}}"

  - name: gen-number-list
    script:
      image: python:alpine3.6
      command: [python]
      source: |
        import json
        import sys
        print("abc")
        print("def")
        print("1, 2, 3")
  - name: sleep-n-sec
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: seconds
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["echo sleeping for {{inputs.parameters.seconds}} seconds; sleep {{inputs.parameters.seconds}}; echo done"]
```

As I am not able to adapt the python-script I cannot use the standard-solution as shown below:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-param-result-
spec:
  entrypoint: loop-param-result-example
  templates:
  - name: loop-param-result-example
    steps:
    - - name: generate
        template: gen-number-list
    - - name: sleep
        template: sleep-n-sec
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: seconds
            value: "{{item}}"
        withParam: "{{steps.generate.outputs.result}}"

  - name: gen-number-list
    script:
      image: python:alpine3.6
      command: [python]
      source: |
        import json
        import sys
        json.dump([i for i in range(20, 31)], sys.stdout)
  - name: sleep-n-sec
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: seconds
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["echo sleeping for {{inputs.parameters.seconds}} seconds; sleep {{inputs.parameters.seconds}}; echo done"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got the

```
command: [ python ]
source |
    import json
```

to work, however, this works for me:

```
    command: [ python, -c ]
    args: &script
    - |
        import json
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
  - name: gen-number-list
    script:
      image: python:alpine3.6
      command: [python]
      source: |
        import json
        import sys
        print("abc")
        print("def")
        print("1, 2, 3") # Incorrect
```

I think you meant:

```
  - name: gen-number-list
    script:
      image: python:alpine3.6
      command: [python]
      source: |
        import json
        import sys
        print("abc")
        print("def")
        print("[1, 2, 3]") # Correct
```

Because the expected output is a JSON array. Despite that, it won't work because the entire stdout is considered and not just the last line.

To solve it, you can use [Output Parameters](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/walk-through/output-parameters) instead of [Scripts Results](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/walk-through/scripts-and-results):

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-param-result-
spec:
  entrypoint: loop-param-result-example
  templates:
  - name: loop-param-result-example
    steps:
    - - name: generate
        template: gen-number-list
    - - name: sleep
        template: sleep-n-sec
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: seconds
            value: "{{item}}"
        withParam: "{{steps.generate.outputs.parameters.numbers}}"

  - name: gen-number-list
    outputs:
      parameters:
       - name: numbers
         valueFrom:
            path: /tmp/numbers.txt
    script:
      image: python:alpine3.6
      command: [python]
      source: |
        import json
        import sys
        print("abc")
        print("def")
        with open("/tmp/numbers.txt", "w") as outfile:
          json.dump([i for i in range(1, 4)], outfile)
      volumeMounts:
      - name: numbers
        mountPath: /tmp
    volumes:
    - name: numbers
      emptyDir: { }
  - name: sleep-n-sec
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: seconds
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["echo sleeping for {{inputs.parameters.seconds}} seconds; sleep {{inputs.parameters.seconds}}; echo done"]
```